# Error installing open-cv | windows | anaconda | python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, windows, opencv, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install Open-cv on anaconda prompt but every time I start installation using

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

it shows me different errors, I have tried installing OpenCV using cmd but it shows:

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\wajid\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (4.5.1.48)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\users\wajid\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.20.2)
```

what does this mean? Checked on jupyter notebook it shows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I have only single version of python installed on my laptop.

Comment: Have you tried using `conda` instead of `pip`?

Comment: No, I didn't, let me try that.

Comment: You flagged anaconda, so I am assuming that you have anaconda installed? At the same time, you also have a `c:\users\wajid\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32`, which is not an anaconda installation. Can you clarify? Also, please add the error you get when using conda to install

Comment: Yes, I'm using anaconda, python is installed separately and the package is installed in that folder, should I change the directory for package installation so anaconda can recognize it ? @FlyingTeller